# DevExpress column a multi select field

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to create a drop down / combo box in dev express with check boxes, to allow the user to select multiple options.

Something like this:

[image: Untitled]

I've found some documentation but nothing that tells me what to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use checkedComboBoxEdit control and use it's drop down list as you want..

Refer - [CheckedComboBoxEdit - add AllowMultiSelect property](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S134210.aspx) devexpress thread and attached example..

you can easily implement the required logic manually using a piece of code. Simply handle the SelectedIndexChanged event and check the selected items.

Hope this help...